# How to parse XML with nokogiri without losing HTML entities?

Tags: html, ruby, nokogiri

If you look at the output below in the after section ruby is removing all the html entities. How to parse XML with nokogiri without loosing HTML entities?

```
--- BEFORE ---

<blog:entryFull>
&lt;p&gt;&lt;iframe src="http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F39858946&amp;amp;show_artwork=true" width="100%" height="166" frameborder="no" scrolling="no"&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;&lt;/p&gt;</blog:entryFull>

--- AFTER --- 

<blog:entryFull>
piframe src="http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F39858946amp;show_artwork=true" width="100%" height="166" frameborder="no" scrolling="no"/iframe/p</blog:entryFull>
  </blog:example>
```

Here is the code:

```
f = File.open(item)

contents = ""
f.each {|line|
  contents << line
}

puts "--- BEFORE ---"
puts contents
puts "--- AFTER ---"

doc = Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse(contents) 
puts doc
f.close
```

Comment: `puts doc` will try to stringify the doc, which isn't what you want. You've got to tell Nokogiri how you want to see the doc/node, as HTML, XHTML or XML. More information is in [the Nokogiri::XML::Node documentation](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html).

Comment: I've got a related issue: `puts Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse( "<pre>&lt;div>foo&lt;/div></pre>" )` gives `<pre>&lt;div&gt;foo&lt;/div&gt;</pre>` but `puts Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse( "&nbsp;<pre>&lt;div>foo&lt;/div></pre>" )` gives `"<pre>div&gt;foo/div&gt;</pre>"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test file might have some invalid HTML entities.

### nokogiri.rb:

```
require 'nokogiri'

puts "--- INVALID ---"
invalid_xml = <<-XML
<blog:entryFull>invalid M&Ms</blog:entryFull><!-- invalid M and M's -->
<blog:entryFull>
&lt;p&gt;&lt;iframe src="http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F39858946&amp;amp;show_artwork=true" width="100%" height="166" frameborder="no" scrolling="no"&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;&lt;/p&gt;</blog:entryFull>
XML

doc = Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse(invalid_xml)
puts doc

puts "--- VALID ---"
valid_xml = <<-XML
<blog:entryFull>valid M&amp;Ms</blog:entryFull><!-- valid M and M's -->
<blog:entryFull>
&lt;p&gt;&lt;iframe src="http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F39858946&amp;amp;show_artwork=true" width="100%" height="166" frameborder="no" scrolling="no"&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;&lt;/p&gt;</blog:entryFull>
XML

doc = Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse(valid_xml)
puts doc
```

### result:

```
$ ruby nokogiri.rb
--- INVALID ---
<blog:entryFull>invalid M</blog:entryFull><!-- invalid M and M's -->
<blog:entryFull>
piframe src="http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F39858946amp;show_artwork=true" width="100%" height="166" frameborder="no" scrolling="no"/iframe/p</blog:entryFull>
--- VALID ---
<blog:entryFull>valid M&amp;Ms</blog:entryFull><!-- valid M and M's -->
<blog:entryFull>
&lt;p&gt;&lt;iframe src="http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F39858946&amp;amp;show_artwork=true" width="100%" height="166" frameborder="no" scrolling="no"&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;&lt;/p&gt;</blog:entryFull>
```

so,

1. Fix input XML
2. Use STRICT ParseOptions

### strict parsing example:

```
invalid_xml = <<-XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <blog:entryFull>invalid M&Ms</blog:entryFull>
  <blog:entryFull>
  &lt;p&gt;&lt;iframe src="http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F39858946&amp;amp;show_artwork=true" width="100%" height="166" frameborder="no" scrolling="no"&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;&lt;/p&gt;</blog:entryFull>
</root>
XML

begin
  doc = Nokogiri::XML(invalid_xml) do |configure|
    configure.strict # strict parsing
  end
  puts doc
rescue => e
  puts 'INVALID XML'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Qambar, I am unable to recreate your issue. However, I am able to produce your desired output given these files/input:

**test.xml**

```
<blog:entryFull> &lt;p&gt;&lt;iframe src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F39858946&amp;amp;show_artwork=true%22" width="100%" height="166" frameborder="no" scrolling="no"&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;&lt;/p&gt;</blog:entryFull>
```

**nokogiri.rb**

```
require 'nokogiri'

f = File.open("./test.html")

contents = ""
f.each {|line|
  contents << line
}

puts "--- BEFORE ---"
puts contents
puts "--- AFTER ---"

doc = Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse(contents) 
puts doc.inner_html
f.close
```

**Console**

```
Development/Code » ruby nokogiri.rb
--- BEFORE ---
<blog:entryFull> &lt;p&gt;&lt;iframe src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F39858946&amp;amp;show_artwork=true%22" width="100%" height="166" frameborder="no" scrolling="no"&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;&lt;/p&gt;</blog:entryFull>
--- AFTER ---
<blog:entryFull> &lt;p&gt;&lt;iframe src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F39858946&amp;amp;show_artwork=true%22" width="100%" height="166" frameborder="no" scrolling="no"&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;&lt;/p&gt;</blog:entryFull>
```

Comment: The test.html file is incorrect. It should have an xml tag containing the escaped HTML like i said in the question '<blog:entryFull>
&lt;p&gt;&lt;iframe src="http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F39858946&amp;amp;show_artwork=true" width="100%" height="166" frameborder="no" scrolling="no"&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;&lt;/p&gt;</blog:entryFull>
'

Comment: I have more than 10k files with many XML tags of which one of it is this one containing full HTML.

Comment: I modified the test file to include the content you specified and am still returning the same content before/after. Not sure what is going on here :/

Comment: i am using ruby 1.9.3p545 (2014-02-24 revision 45159) [x86_64-darwin13.1.0], which version are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

The work-around that i did was to fetch the xml tag through regex and then convert html entities using html entities. Then parse it with nokogiri html parser.