# Ruby Regex to find iframes that do not have Youtube, Vimeo or Soundcloud in src?

Tags: html, ruby, regex

I want to write a regex to ignore iframes containing urls from youtube, vimeo or soundcloud in a string encoded with HTML entities.

This is what i tried and is not working. Some sample texts are given below

REGEX

```
&lt;iframe(^?youtube|soundcloud|vimeo)*\/iframe
```

SAMPLE TEXT

```
&lt;p&gt;&lt;iframe src="http://www.3you3tube.com/embed/YoX1yc92MOU" width="500" height="300" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
29  &lt;p&gt;text daily to place domain staff as volunteers with charity partners, we know all too well that the "V" word can sometimes be misunderstood. Occasionally seen as a dusty, worthy word, it can conjure images of coffee mornings and bric-a-brac stalls. So its not always as easy as you might think to get people to embrace their inner-volunteer. That's why the &lt;a href="http://www.domain.co.uk/sdfn/2010/11/connect-create-domain-volunteers.shtml"&gt;Conne
```

SAMPLE OUTPUT

```
&lt;iframe src="http://www.3you3tube.com/embed/YoX1yc92MOU" width="500" height="300" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;
```

SAMPLE TEXT

```
&lt;p&gt;&lt;iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/YoX1yc92MOU" width="500" height="300" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
29  &lt;p&gt;text daily to place domain staff as volunteers with charity partners, we know all too well that the "V" word can sometimes be misunderstood. Occasionally seen as a dusty, worthy word, it can conjure images of coffee mornings and bric-a-brac stalls. So its not always as easy as you might think to get people to embrace their inner-volunteer. That's why the &lt;a href="http://www.domain.co.uk/sdfn/2010/11/connect-create-domain-volunteers.shtml"&gt;Conne
```

SAMPLE OUTPUT

```
nil
```

Just to be clear:

i want to ignore iframes which have youtube, vimeo or soundcloud in them.

and i am testing it on rubular
http://rubular.com/r/F9x6SSkIfu

Comment: This isn't a good use of regular expressions. HTML can vary too much for a pattern to handle. Instead, decode the entities back into HTML, then use a parser, such as Nokogiri, which will normalize the HTML, making it easy to ignore differences in order, whitespace, capitalization, etc.

Comment: i tried your mentioned solution and it seems like the data is not very consistent. There are several broken tags which are causing nokogiri not to parse the HTML string properly. One of the examples is this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25596881/how-to-parse-xml-with-nokogiri-without-losing-html-entities/25604318#25604318

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
&lt;iframe.*?src="(?![^"]*(?:youtube|vimeo|soundcloud)).*?&lt;\/iframe&gt;
```

[***Demo***](http://regex101.com/r/qD6xE5/2)

---

The key here is `iframe.*?src="(?=[^"]*(?:youtube|vimeo|soundcloud))`, so let me expand that for you:

```
iframe                          ?# literally match iframe
.*?                             ?# lazily match 0+ characters
src="                           ?# literally match src="
(?!                             ?# start negative lookahead assertion
  [^"]*                         ?# match 0+ non-" characters
  (?:youtube|vimeo|soundcloud)  ?# match one of the domains
)                               ?# end assertion
```

So as soon as the expression reaches an `iframe`'s `src` attribute, it will negatively assert for one of the domains after any number of non-`"` characters (in other words, until the end of the `src` attribute). As long as we don't find one of these domains in the attribute, we continue on by lazily matching the rest of the `iframe` (until the closing tag).

Comment: @QambarRaza [this](http://rubular.com/r/DyDSpf9beF) and [this](http://rubular.com/r/uemIQqdTWJ)..?

Comment: that is exactly what i wanted !

Comment: just to let you know the solution was: /&lt;iframe.*?src="(?![^"]*(?:youtube|vimeo|soundcloud)).*?&lt;\/iframe&gt;/m

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
.*?iframe src=".*?(?:youtube|soundcloud|vimeo).*?".*|(.*?iframe src=".*?".*)
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/lP9jR6/2)**

You can see that for the first input (the green one) there output is what you specified in the question. For the blue match there is no output since it is a valid match for youtube, soundcloud or vimeo.

[image]

Match information

```
MATCH 1
1.  [0-155] `&lt;p&gt;&lt;iframe src="http://www.3you3tube.com/embed/YoX1yc92MOU" width="500" height="300" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;&lt;/p&gt;`
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML is notoriously difficult to parse using regular expressions *unless* you own the generation of that HTML, and, even then it's a pain.

Instead, for anything beyond the most trivial use, go for a parser, which can normalize away a lot of the problems that make a pattern fail.

The patterns submitted will fail because they assume tag-name case, whitespace and string delimiters for the src parameter. Those could be accommodated in the pattern, but it's easier to not bother. In the following code, all the strings being checked are valid HTML:

```
require 'htmlentities'
require 'nokogiri'

[
  %#&lt;p&gt;&lt;iframe\nsrc="http://www.youtube.com/embed/YoX1yc92MOU_1"&lt;/iframe&gt;&lt;/p&gt;#,
  %#&lt;p&gt;&lt;iframe\nsrc= "http://www.youtube.com/embed/YoX1yc92MOU_2"&lt;/iframe&gt;&lt;/p&gt;#,
  %#&lt;p&gt;&lt;iframe\nsrc = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/YoX1yc92MOU_3"&lt;/iframe&gt;&lt;/p&gt;#,
  %#&lt;p&gt;&lt;iframe\nsrc = 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/YoX1yc92MOU_4'&lt;/iframe&gt;&lt;/p&gt;#,
  %#&lt;p&gt;&lt;Iframe\nsrc = 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/YoX1yc92MOU_5'&lt;/iframe&gt;&lt;/p&gt;#,
  %#&lt;p&gt;&lt;IFRAME\nsrc = 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/YoX1yc92MOU_6'&lt;/iframe&gt;&lt;/p&gt;#,
  %#&lt;p&gt;&lt;IFRAME\nsrc =
  'http://www.youtube.com/embed/YoX1yc92MOU_7'&lt;/iframe&gt;&lt;/p&gt;#,
].each do |text|
  html = HTMLEntities::Decoder.new('html4').decode(text)
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(html)

  iframe = doc.at('iframe')
  puts "Ignoring: #{ iframe['src'] }" if iframe['src'][/\b(?:youtube|soundcloud|vimeo)\b/i]
end
# >> Ignoring: http://www.youtube.com/embed/YoX1yc92MOU_1
# >> Ignoring: http://www.youtube.com/embed/YoX1yc92MOU_2
# >> Ignoring: http://www.youtube.com/embed/YoX1yc92MOU_3
# >> Ignoring: http://www.youtube.com/embed/YoX1yc92MOU_4
# >> Ignoring: http://www.youtube.com/embed/YoX1yc92MOU_5
# >> Ignoring: http://www.youtube.com/embed/YoX1yc92MOU_6
# >> Ignoring: http://www.youtube.com/embed/YoX1yc92MOU_7
```

"[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)" is an obligatory link on Stack Overflow when these sort of questions arise. The most famous answer is tongue-in-cheek of course, but it makes the point not to do this with patterns.

In the code above, `/\b(?:youtube|soundcloud|vimeo)\b/i` is a regular expression, but it is short and sweet and isn't applied to the HTML at all. Instead, it's used against the content of the src parameter, which has to be correct in the (encoded) HTML and can't be mangled/munged, otherwise the iframe itself would not work.